# Registration script doesn't do anything

Tags: php, html

Ok, so I'm learning php and today I wanted to learn about making a user registration page.

I wrote this code :-
php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '') or die ('Unable to Connect.Check your connection parameters');
mysql_select_db('stock_inventory', $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$usernamer=(isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$passwordr=(isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$emailr=(isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$usernamer=strip_tags($usernamer);
$passwordr=strip_tags($passwordr);
$emailr=strip_tags($emailr);
$errors[]=array();
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'register')
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ' . $usernamer;
    $result=mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo "Username already exists.";
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "Redirecting";
        header('Refresh: 3; URL=register.php');
    }
    if(empty($usernamer))
    {
        $errors[]="Username cannot be blank";
    }
else if(empty($passwordr))
{
    $errors[]="Password cannot be empty";
}
else if(empty($emailr))
{
    $errors[]="Email Cannot be empty";
}
else if(count($errors) > 0)
{
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($errors as $error)
    {
        echo '<td>' . $error . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    die();
}
else
{
$query = 'INSERT INTO user
          (user_id, user_name, user_password, user_email)
          VALUES
          (NULL, "' . mysql_real_escape_string($usernamer, $db) . '", "' . PASSWORD($passwordr) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($emailr, $db) . '")';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
if($result)
{
    echo "Registration Succssfull";
}
else
{
    echo "Error in registration";
}

}
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="register.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="register" value="register" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem :-
Unfortunately, this script does nothing.
Doesn't matter I'm entering anything or not, it does nothing.
How can I fix this ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: why are you inserting NULL values in userid field ?

Comment: You say it doesnt do anything? Does that mean the page wont even submit, it does it submit and then do nothing? If the first case, check if you might have some javascript stopping the submit (like a validationscript)

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: SQL injection warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Add this to your php-files and check if there are any errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @Maximus2012 user_id is set to AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: then you don't need to specify user_id field (or its value) in your insert query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submit button is named register, not submit, so this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'register')
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['register']) && $_POST['register'] == 'register')
```

that is why it does nothing.

Comment: Ok, I get this :- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Your username variable is not correctly escaped.

Comment: datasage is right, it should be: 
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ' ".$usernamer." ' ";

Note the double quotes on the outside of the query, which lets you use the single inner quotes to denote a sql string around the username, which should work.